# Mapping a shared folder on Windows from a Windows Server on Google Cloud Compute

Tags: file, cloud, google-compute-engine, sharing, windows-server-2019

Good morning. I recently installed Windows Server 2019 on Google Cloud Compute Engine and in there I installed a copy of 5 user copy SAGE 50 Premium 2020. I have given the server a static IP, and I have shared the Peachtree/Company folder on the Windows Server 2019, but I don't know how to access this shared folder from my Laptop or other desktops in the office. The local Sage installations in the office require access to this folder that is on the Windows Server, on the Compute Engine.

I read in some places that we require a VPN but even that I'm not sure how to set up withing the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect your on-premises network with your cloud VM via VPN tunnel and then you'll be able to use windows sharing options.

Have a look at [Google Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/). Also, you can check available option at `Marketplace` using keyword `VPN` in case you prefer or more familiar with other VPN solutions like [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/google-cloud-vpn/). Don't forget to setup your firewall and routing options accordingly to the documentation of selected VPN.